# Дан двумерный массив целых чисел a из n строк и m столбцов. Требуется определить координаты (индексы+1) всех максимальных элементов в массиве

Tags: c++, матрицы

````
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, m, k = 0;
  //входные данные 2 3
                 //7 10 9
                 //10 -6 10
    int a[100][100];
    int imax = 0, jmax = 0, imin = 0, jmin = 0;
    cin >> n >> m;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    cin >> a[i][j];
  }
}
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if(a[i][j] > a[imax][jmax]){
              imax = i;
              jmax = j;
              k++;
            }
        }
    }
  for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
    cout << imax + 1 << " " << jmax + 1 << endl;
    }
  //выводит только 1 2
  // а должен 2 3
            //7 10 9
            //10 -6 10
    return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: выводить не одну координату надо, а все. Это можно сделать ещё одним циклом по матрице, сравнивая с этим максимальным элементом, и выводя их координаты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сохраняете индексы **только одного** максимального элемента. Сохранять их все при первом проходе вы не можете, так как не знаете, чему же равен максимум.

Поэтому вам надо просто найти максимальное значение, а потом еще раз пройтись по всем элементам.

Максимально приближенно к вашему коду (хотя я бы использовал вектора, раз уж у вас С++):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m, M;
    cin >> n >> m;
    //входные данные 2 3
    //7 10 9
    //10 -6 10
    int **a = new int*[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) a[i] = new int[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    }

    M = a[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if(a[i][j] > M) M = a[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if(a[i][j] == M) cout << i+1 << "  " << j+1 << endl;
        }
    }

}
```

См. https://ideone.com/JMw0FA

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Потому что вы выводите  `k` раз одни и те же значения.
Этот счетчик вам не нужен, нужно вывести все индексы элементов, которые имеют те же значения, что и a[imax][jmax]:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
            if (a[i][j] == a[imax][jmax]) 
                cout << i + 1 << " " << j + 1 << endl;
```

В данном примере вы могли бы определить максимальный элемент при вводе и написать цикл для вывода.